# Cloudera Spark Submit Class Not Found

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera

I'm trying to run a very simple application on a standard Cloudera Quickstart installation (latest version 5.10).

I am getting a class not found exception no matter what I try. Here is my submit script:

```
#!/bin/bash

spark-submit \
  --class com.message.generator.MessageGeneratorMain \
  --master local[*] \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --queue app-protected \
  --executor-memory 3G \
  --driver-memory 3G \
  --num-executors 2 \
  --verbose \
  /opt/spark/message_generator-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

And the simple main class that I need it to access:

```
package com.message.generator

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object MessageGeneratorMain {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Creating Spark Context...")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("message_generator")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    //val kafkaGenerator: main.scala.KafkaGenerator = new main.scala.KafkaGenerator()
    //kafkaGenerator.testRandomSerializedMessages()

    new Thread(new MessageGenerator).start()
  }
}
```

Pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ro.ace.ucv</groupId>
    <artifactId>message_generator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatest.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-with-dependencies</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Exception I am getting is:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.message.generator.MessageGeneratorMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Did you confirm in your jar that the path `com.message.generator.MessageGeneratorMain` is correct?

Comment: Following up on Ramesh's question: Can you do `jar -tf /opt/spark/message_generator-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar | grep -i MessageGeneratorMain` and see what comes out?

Comment: You're right the class is not getting packaged. My code isn't getting packaged, only the dependencies...